# How to remove Unselected row id from string array in JQGrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I cannot remove the value in selectedrowid when I uncheck a check box from the jqgrid. And I tried like the following,

```
var selectedRowId = $('#{0}').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
for (var i = 0; i < selectedRowId.length; i++) {
    cellValue = $('#{0}').jqGrid('getCell', selectedRowId[i], '{3}');
    stringArray[i] = cellValue;
}
```

And this code is appended in htmlhelper class. So If I uncheck a check box from the jqgrid, I want to remove the id from the selectedrowid. How to do this?

Comment: can you elaborate more? I do not understand what do you want? are you having problems with `.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');`?

Comment: What is `stringArray[]`? And also i can't even see that you're trying to remove some thing. I can only see that you set array's element

Comment: Actually, I did not put any code which is removing. But I told what I need that is, I am storing the id value to a variable named selectedrowid for selected rows in jqgrid and if I unselect a row then the row id should be removed from the stored variable. @teo van kot

Comment: will stringArray contain unique values?

Comment: Yes stringArray contain unique Values. @ Vimalan Jaya Ganesh